# How to send RequestTag in Lambda function to spin up EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tags, amazon-emr

My lambda function is to spin up a transient EMR. I am getting the error below:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: User: arn:aws:sts::111111111115:assumed-role/lambda-eks-role/transient_job is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:ap-southeast-1:111111111115:cluster/* because no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow action",
```

The above is a result of the IAM role condition below:

```
{
        "Sid": "RunJobFlowExplicitlyWithEMRManagedTag",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true"
            }
        }
}
```

I was told to pass the above tag (i.e., "for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true") when I create my cluster. How do I do that? Every time I search for Lambda and RequestTag, I'm not getting anything relevant.

FYI, I have no privilege to change the IAM roles. I was told by the admin, and the exact words were: "Can you add this tag (for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true") to the cluster you are creating"

I believe I have to add the tag in the function launch_transient_emr() but I have no idea where exactly and how (and I'm still searching online for any relevant information). Any guidance is appreciated.

A snippet of my Lambda Code:

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.parse

### Steps Configs (under function 'get_emr_step')
TODAY_DATE = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d") + datetime.today().strftime("%H%M%s")[:-3]

JOB_TYPE_MAPPING = {
    'cowrie': {
        'job-script-path': 's3://bucket-test-transient/transient-job-scripts/emr_type1_job.py',
        'output_file_name': 'type1-results/' 
    },
    'suricata': {
        'job-script-path': 's3://bucket-test-transient/transient-job-scripts/emr_type2_job.py',
        'output_file_name': 'type2-results/' 
    }
}

### EMR Job Running Configs (under function 'launch_transient_emr')
CLUSTER_NAME = 'transient_emr_cluster_'+TODAY_DATE # TODO: insert some cluster name
LOGURI = os.environ['LOGURI']
RELEASE_LABEL = os.environ['RELEASE_LABEL'] 
EBS_ROOT_VOLUME_SIZE = os.environ['EBS_ROOT_VOLUME_SIZE']

# Instance Variables
MASTER_INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['MASTER_INSTANCE_TYPE']
SLAVE_INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['SLAVE_INSTANCE_TYPE']
INSTANCE_COUNT = os.environ['INSTANCE_COUNT']
EC2_SUBNET_ID = os.environ['EC2_SUBNET_ID']

# Roles
JOB_FLOW_ROLE = os.environ['JOB_FLOW_ROLE']
SERVICE_ROLE = os.environ['SERVICE_ROLE']

# Bootstrap
BOOTSTRAP_PATH = os.environ['BOOTSTRAP_PATH']

# Output File Configs
OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME']


def get_emr_step(job_type, source_bucket_name, source_key):
    job_date = source_key.split("/")[1]
    spark_steps = [
            {
                "Name": job_type+"-daily-job-"+job_date+"-"+TODAY_DATE,
                "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
                "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                        "sudo",
                        "spark-submit",
                        "--deploy-mode",
                        "client",
                        JOB_TYPE_MAPPING[job_type]["job-script-path"],
                        "--input_bucket_name",
                        source_bucket_name,
                        "--input_key_name",
                        source_key,
                        "--output_bucket_name",
                        OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME,
                        "--output_file_name",
                        JOB_TYPE_MAPPING[job_type]["output_file_name"]
                    ],
                }
            }
        ]
    return spark_steps


def launch_transient_emr(spark_steps):
    client = get_emr_client()
    response = client.run_job_flow(
        Name = CLUSTER_NAME,
        LogUri = LOGURI,
        ReleaseLabel = RELEASE_LABEL,
        EbsRootVolumeSize = EBS_ROOT_VOLUME_SIZE,
        Instances={
            'MasterInstanceType': MASTER_INSTANCE_TYPE,
            'SlaveInstanceType': SLAVE_INSTANCE_TYPE,
            'InstanceCount': INSTANCE_COUNT,
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
            'TerminationProtected': False,
            'Ec2SubnetId': EC2_SUBNET_ID
            
        },
        Applications = [ {'Name': 'Spark'} ],
        Configurations = [
            { 
                'Classification': 'spark-hive-site',
                'Properties': {
                    'hive.metastore.client.factory.class': 'com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory'}
            },
            {
                "Classification": "spark", 
                "Properties": {
                    "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "Classification": "spark-defaults", 
                "Properties": {
                    "spark.executorEnv.ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT":"1", 
                    "spark.network.timeout":"1500"
                }
            },
            {
                "Classification": "hdfs-site", 
                "Properties": {
                    "dfs.replication":"2"
                }
            },
            {
                "Classification": "livy-conf", 
                "Properties": {
                    "livy.server.session.timeout": "10h"
                }
            },
            {
                "Classification": "emrfs-site", 
                "Properties": {
                    "fs.s3.maxConnections":"100"
                }
            }
        ],
        VisibleToAllUsers = True,
        JobFlowRole = JOB_FLOW_ROLE,
        ServiceRole = SERVICE_ROLE,
        Steps = spark_steps,
        BootstrapActions = [
            {
                'Name': 'string',
                'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                    'Path': BOOTSTRAP_PATH
                }
            }
        ]
    )
    return response

def get_emr_client():
    return boto3.client("emr")

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        job_type = 'type1' if 'type1' in source_key else 'type2'
    

        spark_steps = get_emr_step(job_type, source_bucket_name, source_key)
        response = launch_transient_emr(spark_steps)
        
        return {"status" :"Successfully launched EMR cluster"}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: Ask your admin what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html

Focus now on this image
[image]

The key you need is **for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies** and the value is **true**. You can follow the same approach you did for the steps. Your admin is right.

Comment: Thanks Dan. This was a better feedback then "Ask your admin what to do". I did asked but he knows it could be done but forgotten the details.

However, before you posted this, I had already found the above link and from that link I used the Python link at the bottom of the page in "See Also" section to get the answer I need.